# How to compute residuals from OpenCV fitLine?

Tags: python, performance, opencv, numpy

I'm fitting a line to 3D points with [OpenCV fitLine](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitline). What's the best way to calculate residuals of the resulting fit? Or, since I want residuals in addition to the fit, is there a better method than fitLine?

The following works, but there must be a better (faster) way.

```
# fit points
u, v, w, x, y, z = cv2.fitLine(points, cv2.DIST_L2, 0, 1, 0.01)
v = np.array(u[0], v[0], w[0])
p = np.array(x[0], y[0], z[0])

# rotate fit to z axis
k = np.cross(v, [0, 0, 1])
mag = np.linalg.norm(k)
R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(k * np.arcsin(mag) / mag)

# rotate points and calculate distance to z-axis
rot_points = np.dot(R, (points-p).T)
err = rot_points[0]**2 + rot_points[1]**2
```

I'm assuming that `fitLine` computes the residuals `err` while estimating the line, so it is a waste to have to recompute them myself. Basically, knowing that I want the line *and* the residuals, is there a better alternative than fitLine, which only returns the line?

Comment: What's the typical shape of `points` that you are working with? Also, I am assuming `v` and `p` to be `1D` arrays of `3` elements each. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head, probably `(~2000, 3)`. And yes, `v` is a (3d) vector colinear with the fit line, and `p` is a (3d) point on the fit line.

Comment: I should note that python code that does not use `fitLine`, but still produces `v`, `p`, and `err` would be great. Basically, I'm assuming that the residuals are computed by `fitLine`, so it's a waste to have to compute them again.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any direct method to get the sum of residuals from `cv2.fitLine` itself and I would  be focusing solely on speeding up the existing code. Now, upon benchmarking with a relatively high number of points, it shows up that the most of the runtime is spent at the last two lines, where we get `rot_points` and `err`. Also, it seems that we are not exactly using the last row of `rot_points` for calculating `err`, so hopefully we can shave off some percentage of runtime by slicing into the first two rows only.

Let's dive into researching efficient ways to obtain `rot_points` and `err`.

**1) rot_points = np.dot(R, (points-p).T)**

This step involves broadcasting in `points-p`, which is reduced by matrix-multiplication later on. Now, `broadcasting` involves heavy memory usage, which in this case can be skipped if we split up the `matrix-multiplication` of `R` with `points` and `p` separately. Also, let's bring in the first two rows of slicing as discussed earlier. Thus, we could get the first two rows of `rot_points` like so -

```
rot_points_row2 = np.dot(R[:2], (points.T)) - np.dot(R[:2],p[:,None])
```

**2) err = rot_points[0]**2 + rot_points[1]**2**

This second step could be sped up with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for efficient `squaring` and `sum-reduction`, like so -

```
err = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',rot_points_row2,rot_points_row2)
```

For a *relatively small* number of points as `2000`, the step to calculate `mag` : `mag = np.linalg.norm(k)` might become significant too in terms of runtime. So, to speed that up, one could alternatively use `np.einsum` again, like so -

```
mag = np.sqrt(np.einsum('i,i->',k,k))
```

---

### Runtime test

Let's use a random array of `2000` points in `3D` space as the input `points` and look at the associated runtime numbers with the original approach and the proposed ones for the last two lines.

```
In [44]: # Setup input points
    ...: N = 2000
    ...: points = np.random.rand(N,3)
    ...: 
    ...: u, v, w, x, y, z = cv2.fitLine(points, cv2.DIST_L2, 0, 1, 0.01)
    ...: v = np.array([u[0], v[0], w[0]])
    ...: p = np.array([x[0], y[0], z[0]])
    ...: 
    ...: # rotate fit to z axis
    ...: k = np.cross(v, [0, 0, 1])
    ...: mag = np.linalg.norm(k)
    ...: R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(k * np.arcsin(mag) / mag)
    ...: 
    ...: # rotate points and calculate distance to z-axis
    ...: rot_points = np.dot(R, (points-p).T)
    ...: err = rot_points[0]**2 + rot_points[1]**2
    ...:
```

Let's run our proposed methods and verify their outputs against the original outputs -

```
In [45]: rot_points_row2 = np.dot(R[:2], (points.T)) - np.dot(R[:2],p[:,None]) 
    ...: err2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',rot_points_row2,rot_points_row2)
    ...: 

In [46]: np.allclose(rot_points[:2],rot_points_row2)
Out[46]: True

In [47]: np.allclose(err,err2)
Out[47]: True
```

Finally and most importantly, let's time these sections of code -

```
In [48]: %timeit np.dot(R, (points-p).T) # Original code
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.5 µs per loop

In [49]: %timeit np.dot(R[:2], (points.T)) - np.dot(R[:2],p[:,None]) # Proposed
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.7 µs per loop

In [50]: %timeit rot_points[0]**2 + rot_points[1]**2  # Original code
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop

In [51]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->j',rot_points_row2,rot_points_row2) # Proposed
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop
```

When the number of points is increased to a huge number, the runtimes look more promising. With `N = 5000000` points, we get -

```
In [59]: %timeit np.dot(R, (points-p).T) # Original code
1 loops, best of 3: 410 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit np.dot(R[:2], (points.T)) - np.dot(R[:2],p[:,None]) # Proposed
1 loops, best of 3: 254 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit rot_points[0]**2 + rot_points[1]**2  # Original code
10 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->j',rot_points_row2,rot_points_row2) # Proposed
10 loops, best of 3: 77.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, the rot_points bit should have been obvious, but the einsum bit will be useful to me in many places. I still feel like I'm recalculating the residuals that must have been calculated during fitLine, but this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that I compared [PCA](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#pca) with [fitLine](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitline) for speed. fitLine was faster than PCA for all the cases where the number of points was greater than ~1000.

PCA directly gives you the eigenvectors, so you don't need the Rodrigues (but this time should be negligible). So, may be, the key to optimization lies in the rest of the code, unless there's a faster way to fit the model, other than fitLine and PCA.

**I don't remember the PCA related math very well, so I could be wrong in the paragraph that follows.**

*Eigenvalues give us the variance along each dimension of the new eigenspace. If we consider a simple 2D case, I think you can take the smaller eigenvalue and multiply it with the number of points N (or is it N-1 ?) in the dataset to obtain the squared-residual-sum. Similarly we can extend it to the 3D case. As PCA gives us the eigenvalues, it takes simple scalar multiplications and additions to get the squared-residual-sum.*

I'm adding the code (c++) for your reference.

```
RNG rng;
float a = -0.1, b = 0.1;
int rows = 3, cols = 1024*2;

Mat data = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_32F);

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    Vec3f& v = data.at<Vec3f>(i);
    v = Vec3f(i+rng.uniform(a, b), i+rng.uniform(a, b), i+rng.uniform(a, b));
}

Mat datat = data.t();

Vec6f line;
fitLine(datat, line, CV_DIST_L2, 0, 1, 0.01);

PCA pca(datat, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);

cout << "fitLine:\n" << line << endl;
cout << "\nPCA:\n" << pca.eigenvalues << endl;
cout << pca.eigenvectors << endl;
```